# Set time zone in iso standard

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set my local time zone in ISO-8601. Been trying with `toISOString()` but can't get it to work. This is the line i need to change.
`i.timestamp = new Date(i.timestamp).toLocaleString('SE')`

Best regards,
Joel

Comment: You can use the toISOString() method provided by the Date object in JavaScript. eg i.timestamp = new Date(i.timestamp).toISOString();

Answer (score 0):

```
const now = new Date();
const localTimezoneOffset = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // convert minutes to milliseconds
const localTime = new Date(now.getTime() - localTimezoneOffset).toISOString();

console.log(localTime);
```